# from a CSV file, count unique value in a row and print the total using python

Tags: python, csv

I am new to Python, I have a CSV file that looks something like this:

```
Date, Profit
02/2019 , 100
03/2019 , 410
03/2019 , 300
04/2019 , 200
```

I need to write a code in Python that print how many unique dates is in the file

Here is what I have so far, but It only print # 1

```
import os
import csv

with open('budget_data.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file,delimiter=',')

    t_dates = [1]
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] not in row:
            t_dates.append(row[0])

    print(len(t_dates))
```

Comment: for starters try pŕinting out reader and see what you get :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `DictReader` that will map the csv headers to the items as a key. You can then use set comprehension to get a list of unique dates and count the length of them.

```py
import csv

with open('test.dat') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=',')
    print(len({row['Date'] for row in reader}))
```